# Handling WM_CLOSE in NSIS

Tags: nsis

How can I handle WM_CLOSE message of a custom page ?

I want to add the app in system tray(using NotifyIcon plugin) when user closes the dialog.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Why WM_CLOSE?

NSIS offers several ways how to handle installer's exit.

You can use `.onUserAbort, .onInstFailed, .onInstSuccess or .onGUIEnd` callbacks to handle various situations.

**.onGUIEnd** is fired everytime (after window closes)

**.onInstSuccess** is fired when the install was successful, right before the install window closes

**.onInstFailed** when the user hits the 'cancel' button after the install has failed

**.onUserAbort** when the user hits the 'cancel' button, and the install hasn't already failed.

As you see all cases are handled, see NSIS manual for details.

Comment: Its because I dont really want the program to close when the user clicks the close button rather want to hide it, add it in the systray and keep it running in background, and only close it when user right clicks the sys tray icon and select exit. Am I asking for too much ?

Comment: So your question is wrong, it has nothing to do with WM_CLOSE. Try to use Notify icon plug-in for your feature: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NotifyIcon_plug-in with some API calls (to minimize window)

Answer (score 0):

As Slappy said, if you just need an "I'm still alive while doing something", [.onGUIEnd](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.7.2.1.5) is your friend:

```
# This callback is called right after the installer window closes.
Function .onGUIEnd

    # Create notify icon (will be always at tray), with default installer icon.
    NotifyIcon::Icon /NOUNLOAD "yitb" 103 "Just a tip" "Balloon!" "Cool!"

    # Launch your process here

    # Remove tray icon.
    NotifyIcon::Icon "r"
FunctionEnd
```

If you are looking for a "minimize to tray" option to just hide the UI, and be able to restore it clicking on the icon, then check [HideWindow](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.14.7) and [ShowWindow](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.14.17).

Comment: "If you are looking for a "minimize to tray" option to just hide the UI, and be able to restore it clicking on the icon, then I have no idea how to do it." ---- Thats exactly what I am asking. :/